# Java: when to serialize non-serializated objects or put them to transient?

Tags: java, serialization

I am puzzled by non-serialized fields, objects in a Serialized object at my new work.
What should be serialized or what should be marked as transient for serialization?

Here is an example:

```
@Stateless
public class NonSerializedThingStateless{
...
}

@RequestScoped
public class NonSerializedThingRequestScoped{
...
}


@Named
@SessionScoped
public class SerializedBean implements Serializable{
  @Inject
  private NonSerializedThingRequestScoped nstrs;

  @Inject
  private NonSerializedThingStateless nsts;

  private List<Something> list; //or something else like POJO

  ...
}
```

Is there a good and simple way where I can tell when I should serialize the Injected or used classes or a guideline?

Is it true I have to choose between serialization and putting things to transient, or are there other ways?

Answer (score 2):

First, a word of warning: You will probably want to use `@Inject` only for the simple cases (usually that would be singletons). For everything else, autowiring works but it can get confusing very fast.

That said, the rule for `transient` is simple: When you *read* the object (deserialize), do you still have **everything** you need to recreate the original state?

If an object depends on the current request, the answer is probably no: At the time when the bean is read from the stream, the request will be long gone.

Comment: @Inject is used almost everywhere, and singletons are pretty rare in this project. So what do you suggest for a request scoped object? Now everything works fine, but of course I would like to improve stability of the program. I have a feeling that I have to choose between serialization or putting them to transient, is it correct, or do I have more options? (I will improve the question)

Comment: If it would take weeks to change the project to "fix" the usage of `@Inject`, it's probably already too late. My suggestion is for new projects or for people who realize some usages of `@Inject` are a constant source of problems. If you can't or don't need to change it, that's fine :-)

Comment: Options: `nstrs` needs to be `transient`. That said, serialization is a very complex topic. Get a framework which allows you to mock an app container. Spring 3.2 has good support to mock HTTP objects and write test cases. Then write tests to make sure the serialization actually does what you expect. Otherwise, it'll become a constant source of bugs.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I am willing to make like this: List has serializable implementation, and even if it is not super-beautiful, I will declare it as ArrayList, it is serializable, I will use transient for RequestScoped, and mark as "FIXME" the rest until I get an idea what way should work the rest.

Comment: I really suggest to start with a unit test to make sure *you* know what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: I will, no cases go without testing.

Answer (score 1):

In web applications, quite often session-scoped variables will be declared as `implements Serializable`. There are a few common reasons for this:

1. A clustered environment (there is more than one app server running your web application) can be configured for *session replication*. In this case, when a user session is changed (eg I add an item to my shopping cart), that change is pushed to all the other app servers in the cluster. These application servers run in different JVMs, and need a way of passing Java objects from one JVM to another. To do this they serialise the session into a stream of bytes and write the bytes to a socket.
2. When a single app server is shutdown (perhaps to have a new web app version deployed), it can be configured to *preserve sessions*, which means that it will typically write the sessions to the disk. When it starts up again, the sessions are read from the disk and recreated in the running web application. Again to do this, the session is serialised to a `byte[]` and written to the file system.

Think about the above two examples when deciding whether a field should be serialized or `transient`. If we do this, then there are a few simple rules. Generally:

1. Anything request-scoped should made `transient`. Eg the search text a user typed in a search field. This information really doesn't need to be persisted, as it's only relevant to the current request.
2. Anything stateless should be made `transient`. The classic example here is a logger. A logger doesn't need to serialised as there's no state that should be saved. The code will continue to run just fine if a new logger was created!
3. Anything session-scoped should be serialized. For example, user preferences or items added to a shopping cart.

So to answer your questions:

*Is there a good and simple way where I can tell when I should serialize the Injected or used classes or a guideline?*

Think about why sessions are serialized (ie what I wrote above) and determine if it makes sense to serialize or not, regardless of whether a field is injected.

*Is it true I have to choose between serialization and putting things to transient, or are there other ways?*

If you are definitely going to be serializing the sessions; then yes, you have to make the choice of what should be serialized and what should be transient. **However**, if you are not running in a clustered environment, you are not saving sessions to disk on shutdown, and there are no other problems; then it is perfectly reasonable not to make anything `Serializable` as no serialisation is going to take place!